# Get the default back indicator image of a Navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, embedded-resource

I want to use the default image of the back button of a navigation controller in
IOS7 elsewhere in my application.
How can i obtain that image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically in runtime, you can't.

What you can is

1. Use extracted elements, e.g. from these sites:

   - http://avexdesigns.com/ios7-psd-templates/
   - http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/
2. Extract it yourself, using [Resource extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor)
3. Snapshot the screen and cut it out yourself (most inconvenient option).

Comment: I used the Resource extractor, but i didn't expect not being able to use the system's built in photos in the app.